# Pull to Refresh and setState not working - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React Native App 
I am implementing Pull to refresh in my Flatlist prop "onRefresh" 
onRefresh called the function "refreshcontrol()" see code below. 
I need to change my state "refreshing" to true before I fetch from my API. But it throws the maximum update error.

```
export default class NotificationScreen extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
      refreshing: false 
    }
  }
.
.
.
.
.
  refreshControl() {
    const { refreshing } = this.state;
    this.setState({ refreshing : true )}.    // throws maximum update error

    return (
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={fetchNotifications.bind(this)}      //fetch from API only when refreshing is true
        colors={['#2B70AD']}
      />
    );
  };


}
```

How else can I set my state to "refreshing :  true" ??? Help please!!!!

This is how it was fixed. Solution:

```
refresh = async() => {
    this.setState({refreshing : true})
    try {
      const notifications = await fetchNotifications();
      this.setState({
        notifications,
        error: null,
        refreshing: false
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({
        notifications: [],
        error,
        refreshing: false
      });
    }
  }

  refreshControl() {
    const { refreshing } = this.state;

    return (
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={this.refresh}
        colors={['#2B70AD']}
      />
    );
  };
```

Comment: your fetchcall to your api does that hold the current items that need to be displayed? so if it is called again the right data should be shown?

Comment: move `this.setState({ refreshing : true )}` into `fetchNotifications` and set that to false when finish fetching

Comment: As soon as I launch my Notification centre, first I set my state "refreshing" to true then "fetchNotification" API will bring all my messages and store it in state "notifications" and change state "refreshing" to false (default). Now when I pull to refresh same process is followed. But I cannot set "refreshing" to true hence I cannot fetch my messages:\

Comment: @Horst importing "fetchNotifications" functions from some other js file.

Comment: I managed to implement refresh controll yesterday by myself - I can show you the code/function if you want maybe you can spot a difference if you like

Comment: @yeslam please do share :)

Comment: @RakshaHegde you want it you get it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  refreshFlatlist = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        refresh: true,
      },
      () => this.getTodosHandler()
    );
    this.setState({
      refresh: false,
    });
  };
```

This is how I refresh the default state of course is false. the todosHandler always holds the current todos. Its a call to a SQLite DB stored on the phone locally.

Now the flatlist RefreshComponent I used:

```
   <FlatList
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={this.state.refresh}
                onRefresh={this.refreshFlatlist}
              />
            }
            extraData={this.state.refresh}
            data={this.state.toDoArray}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => ( ...
```

Look into it maybe it will help you - this works for me like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly. I think there is a typo in your code. You are using try instead of true. I think that might be the cause of the error.

Comment: sorry fixed it. it is "true" and it throws "maximum update error"

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the issue but I'll put it here for others (like me) trying to debug:

Make sure that your list is not put inside a ScrollView!